# IRC /TOPIC command trimming issue in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, irc, asyncsocket

I am using Cocoa async socket library in my iOS application to make connection with an IRC server via Tcp sockets. All the IRC commands are working perfectly except /TOPIC command. 
When I send a topic command it always trim the first two characters in the response. Please check the example wireshark report below.

[image: Request]

[image: Response]

It works on other IRC clients (mIRC). How can I identify the root cause of the issue?

Comment: You have to add a `:` before the final parameter, like `TOPIC #abcdereh :My name is Clement`. If you don't format your messages correctly, the server may do strange things (or nothing).

Comment: Ok, I'll add it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you send your own IRC commands (most IRC clients let you easily inject arbitrary commands with `/command here`), you have to format it correctly, with a `:` before the final parameter if it contains spaces:

```
TOPIC #abcdereh :My name is Clement
```

Most IRC clients have an alias for `/TOPIC` that does that stuff for you.
If you are writing your own client, make sure that you handle the following cases:

- `/TOPIC`: send `TOPIC #currentchannel`
- `/TOPIC #somechannel` send `TOPIC #somechannel`
- `/TOPIC Not a channel` send `TOPIC #currentchannel :Not a channel`
- `/TOPIC #somechannel New Topic` send `TOPIC #somechannel :New Topic`